# How could I sort the coordinates according to the serpentine in the image?

Tags: python, sorting, opencv, scikit-learn, scikit-image

In this following binary image,

[image]

I have been able to get the *list of coordinates* where the value is 1.

The coordinates are stored from *left to right*.

**Question:** *How could I sort the list of coordinates in such a way that they come one after the other and they follow the path of this serpentine?*

***Source Code:***

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

import cv2



from skimage.morphology import skeletonize, skeletonize_3d, medial_axis
diff = cv2.imread('img.png', 0)   
diff = diff.astype('uint8')

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations = 1)



sk = skeletonize_3d(thresh)


pixels = np.argwhere(sk==255)
pixels = np.asarray(pixels)

y = pixels[:,0]
x = pixels[:,1]

L = (x, y) # Question: How can I sort L?

np.savetxt("C:/test.csv", np.c_[L], delimiter = ',', fmt='%f')
```

Any idea how I could possibly go about with this and sort L according to the serpentine?

Comment: You could try [LineIterator](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#lineiterator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a "brute force" way of searching a path in the data. It is without back-tracking, so if there are dead-ends (and maybe lines with bigger width than 1) it will fail to find a "better" path.

Unfortunately C++ code only, but quite simple:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat inputBGR = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/serpentine.png");
    if (inputBGR.empty()) return 0;

    cv::Mat input; // mask
    cv::cvtColor(inputBGR, input, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat mask = input.clone(); // keep the original mask. "input" will be modified during processing.

    cv::Point currentPoint = cv::Point(input.cols, input.rows);
    // find most top-left point:
    cv::Point origin(0, 0);
    for (int y = 0; y < input.rows; ++y)
        for (int x = 0; x < input.cols; ++x)
        {
            cv::Point cPoint = cv::Point(x, y);
            if (input.at<unsigned char>(cPoint))
            if (cv::norm(origin - cPoint) < cv::norm(origin - currentPoint)) // can be optimized by re-using temporary results
            {
                currentPoint = cPoint;
            }
        }

    // now find the path
    std::vector<cv::Point> path;

    // add first point:
    path.push_back(currentPoint);
    input.at<unsigned char>(currentPoint) = 0; // invalidate all used points

    while (true)
    {
        bool foundNeighbor = false;
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = -1; x <= 1; ++x)
            {
                if (y != 0 || x != 0)
                {
                    cv::Point cPoint = currentPoint + cv::Point(x, y);
                    if (cPoint.x < 0 || cPoint.x >= input.cols || cPoint.y < 0 || cPoint.y >= input.rows) continue; // skip points outside of the image

                    /*
                    inputBGR.at<cv::Vec3b>(cPoint) = cv::Vec3b(0,255,0);
                    cv::imshow("debug", inputBGR);
                    cv::waitKey(0);
                    inputBGR.at<cv::Vec3b>(cPoint) = cv::Vec3b(255, 255, 255);
                    */

                    if (input.at<unsigned char>(cPoint))
                    {
                        currentPoint = cPoint;
                        path.push_back(cPoint);
                        input.at<unsigned char>(currentPoint) = 0; // invalidate all used points
                        foundNeighbor = true;
                    }
                }
                if (foundNeighbor) break; // restart on new current point
            }
            if (foundNeighbor) break; // restart on new current point
        }

        if (!foundNeighbor) break; // no more points in path...
    }

    // generate colored output
    cv::Mat output = cv::Mat::zeros(inputBGR.size(), CV_8UC1);

    // color the path...
    float nPoints = path.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < path.size(); ++i)
    {
        float posRel = i / nPoints;
        unsigned char val = 255 * posRel;
        output.at<unsigned char>(path[i]) = val;
    }

    // color code the path from blue to red
    cv::applyColorMap(output, output, cv::COLORMAP_JET);
    output.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0), 255-mask);


    cv::imshow("output", output);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Giving this visualized result:

[image]

the points are in the `path` variable.

Here's pseudo-code:

```
0. search/select a starting point A
1. create a directed list P to construct the path
2. create a memory M to remember which points were already observerd
3. maintain current point C, initialized with A
4. while end not found:
    4.1. for each pixel in direct neighborhood (3x3 region without the center point) with coordinates (x,y)
        4.1.1. if the pixel is white and (x,y) is not yet in M:
            4.1.1.1.  add (x,y) to M
            4.1.1.2.  set C to (x,y)
            4.1.1.3.  add (x,y) to P
            4.1.1.4.  go on with 4.
        4.1.2. if no pixel is white or all the white pixel's coordinates are already in M
            4.1.2.1.  end is found
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I could implement the code and it does work :) If I may ask, could you please explain the code in a line or two as I would like to implement the same in Python. Especially the logic behind find the serpentine?

Comment: the idea is just to start at one end-point and search in the neighborhood of the current point, whether there is another (not yet observed) point available. The usage of the mask and removing already traversed pixels from the mask is just a cheap way to find those yet unused neighbors. If you remind me, I can write some pseudo code with explanation in a week or two, but currently I don't have time :(

Comment: Would it please be possible to send me the pseudo code with a brief explanation, it would help me a lot :) I tried implementing the code in python, but was not fully successful, maybe I am missing a piece of logic,

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the findContours function in cv2 ( `cv2.findContours` ). It can be a bit tricky if you're not used to pyopencv, but the code extract below uses the image from your question (with python2.7).

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('/home/kola/temp/serpentine.png')# change path as necessary
im2 = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
contours = cv2.findContours(im2,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contour = contours[0][0]
# use this section if you want to animate the ploting of the contour
# WARNING - can be slow!!!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.gca().set_xlim(0,im2.shape[1])
plt.gca().set_ylim(im2.shape[0],0)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.ion()
for c in contour:
    plt.plot(c[0][0],c[0][1],'*')
    plt.pause(0.001)
```